# How to pass a data object and KeyEventArgs from a Child Component to a Parent Component in Blazor Server App

Tags: c#, blazor, parameter-passing, keyeventargs

In Blazor Server App I have a Child Component which has a button on it. The Child Componet has some data from the parent bound to (a Book objec). I am calling a click event handler in the parent when I click this button on the Child Component. However, this button clinic event Handler in the parent needs to know wheter the user clicked the button on the chid with Shift Key Pressed or not. I am able to pass the data object (a Book object) from the Child to the parent, but I have not been able to figure out how I pass KeyEventArg also from the Child to the parent, which will help the parent know whether the Shift Key was pressed or not when the user clicked on a button on the child. I would appreciate help.
I include code for my Child Component and Parent Component.

```
// Code for the Child

<div class="card-faheem">
        
        <div >
            <span class="span-fa">@BookContainer.ValueWord</span>
            
        </div>
        <div class="button-div">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" title="View" @onclick="@(async () => await OnSelected.InvokeAsync(BookContainer))">
            <i class="bi bi-binoculars"></i>
        </button>
        </div>
    </div>

@code 
{
    [Parameter, EditorRequired] public TextContainer BookContainer { get; set; } = default!;
    [Parameter, EditorRequired] public EventCallback<TextContainer> OnSelected { get; set; }
}

// Code for the parent
@inject TextContainerRepository tcr
<h3>CardParentPage</h3>

<div >
    @foreach (var book in books)
    {
        <CardComponent BookContainer=book OnSelected="HandleSelectedBook" />
    }
    </div>
@code {

    List<TextContainer> books { get; set; }

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        books = tcr.GetBooksByAuthorName("Jane Auston");

    }


    private void HandleSelectedBook(TextContainer book)
    {
       if (true)
       //     (args.ShiftKey)
        {
            // Do something if ShifKey was pressed
        } else
        {
            // Do something else if ShifKey was no pressed
        }

    }


}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a simple `struct` or `record`, but the simplest in one off situations is the `Tuple`.

```cs
[Parameter, EditorRequired] public EventCallback<Tuple<MouseEventArgs,TextContainer>> OnSelected { get; set; }
```

```cs
 <button class="btn btn-primary" title="View" @onclick="(e) => Selected(e, BookContainer)">

//....

    private async Task Selected(MouseEventArgs e, TextContainer book)
        => await OnSelected.InvokeAsync(new Tuple<MouseEventArgs, TextContainer>(e, book));
```

```cs
    private void HandleSelectedBook(Tuple<MouseEventArgs,TextContainer> data)
    {
        var x = data.Item1.AltKey;

        //.....
    }
```

Here's my demo code:

Component:

```cs
<h3>BookComponent</h3>
<button class="btn btn-success" @onclick="@((e) => OnSelected(e, "Mansfield Park"))">Select Pride and Passion</button>
@code {
    [Parameter] public EventCallback<Tuple<MouseEventArgs, string>> BookSelected { get; set; }

    private async Task OnSelected(MouseEventArgs e, string book)
        => await BookSelected.InvokeAsync(new Tuple<MouseEventArgs, string>(e, book));
}
```

Page:

```cs
@page "/"
<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<BookComponent BookSelected=OnBookSelected />

<div class="alert alert-info">
    @message
</div>

@code {
    private string message = "Not Set";

    private Task OnBookSelected(Tuple<MouseEventArgs,string> data)
    {
        message = data.Item1.ShiftKey ? $"Shifted {data.Item2}" : $"{data.Item2}";
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for providing a solution to my question. I have tried this, but in my parent class when I try to use this event call back I get the error messsage CS1503: Argument 2: "can convert from 'method group' to 'EventCallback' as I show in the image. I would appreciate some further guidance.

Comment: Apologies, but the C# compiler doesn't recognise the Tuple declaration correctly, so I gave you a wrong steer there.  See my revised answer using the conventional full Tuple declaration without named parameters.